# Ubuntu 11.04: `apt-get install rake` -> "E: Unable to locate package rake"

Tags: rake, ubuntu-11.04, apt-get, rackspace

This is probably a type of "is it plugged in?" question, but after getting a default Rackspace image of Ubuntu 11.04 up. Running command (as root)

`apt-get install rake`

Fails with error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rake
```

I'm missing something simple I'm sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that `rake` package is not in the 11.04 sources, but it is in 10.10 sources.

To get `apt-get install rake` to work on 11.04:

Add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe`

`deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe`

Update package listing

`apt-get update`

Now `rake` should be available:

`apt-get install rake`

Answer (score 6):

Try `gem install rake`

It may be better to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) than Ubuntu's Ruby and Gem.