# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: `apt-get install rake` -> “ImportError: No module named rake”

Tags: python, ubuntu, rake

```
I used 'sudo apt-get install rake'.
>>> import rake
but Fails with error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rake
```

Why this happened?I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386794/ubuntu-11-04-apt-get-install-rake-e-unable-to-locate-package-rake

Comment: Yes, I tried.But I didn't get solution from there.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is very confusing. You are installing ruby package to use it in python?

Comment: yes, I already used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got answer.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zelandiya/RAKE-tutorial
$ cd RAKE-tutorial/
:~/RAKE-tutorial$ python
>>> import rake
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use this https://github.com/aneesha/RAKE .

Install using

```
pip install python-rake
```

In code

```
import RAKE
```